# Call a function to delete a row

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a function that is fired on the click of a button. This is in my `ScanDetailActivity` class:

```
Scan scan;
ScanDataSource datasource;

public void doDelete(View v) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "delete clicked");
    datasource.open();
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "going to delete");
    if (datasource.removeFromMyScans(scan)) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Item Deleted");
        setResult(-1);
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "item not deleted");
    }
}
```

This works up to the if statement. I have some log info in the function itself, which is in my 
`ScanDataSource.java` file:

```
public boolean removeFromMyScans(Scan scan) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "removeFromMyScans started");
    String where = ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BID + "=" + scan.getId();
    int result = database.delete(ScanDBOpenHelper.TABLE_BUYS, where, null);
    return (result == 1);
}
```

I never get the "removeFromMyScans started" info. I have looked at the other posts about removing/deleting a row, and I am not even getting to that point. All my error message indicates is that it is failing at the `if (datasource.removeFromMyScans(scan)` line. I am very new to Android development and can't figure out where I am going wrong. I have been learning from the Linda.com videos.

EDIT

Here is the error messages if it will help:

```
I/DATABASE(1985): Table has been created
I/DATABASE(1985): Table buys has column isbn
I/DATABASE(1985): Database opened scans
I/DATABASE(1985): Returned 0 rows in findAll
I/DATABASE(1985): Returned 32160 rows in findAll
I/DATABASE(1985): Database opened scans
I/DATABASE(1985): Returned 1 rows
I/DATABASE(1985): Scan added
I/DATABASE(1985): Returned 1 rows
I/DATABASE(1985): writeToParcel
I/DATABASE(1985): Database closed
I/DATABASE(1985): createFromParcel
I/DATABASE(1985): Parcel constructor
I/DATABASE(1985): delete clicked
D/AndroidRuntime(1985): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(1985): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d3fb20)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1985): Process: com.bookcellaronline.bookscanning, PID: 1985
E/AndroidRuntime(1985): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(1985): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     at com.bookcellaronline.bookscanning.ScanDetailActivity.doDelete(ScanDetailActivity.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(1985):     ... 14 more
I/DATABASE(2027): Database opened scans
I/DATABASE(2027): Returned 32160 rows in findAll
I/DATABASE(2027): Database opened scans
```

ScanDataSource Class:

```
public class ScanDataSource {

    public static final String LOGTAG = "DATABASE";

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    private static final String[] allColumns = {
            ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ISBN, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE,
            ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PRICE, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_IE,
            ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LIMIT, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NOTE, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_RANK,
            ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUPPLY, ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BILLING
    };

    public ScanDataSource(Context context) {
        dbhelper = new ScanDBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() {
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database opened scans");
    }

    public void close() {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database closed");
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    private List<Scan> cursorToScanned(Cursor cursor) {
        List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<Scan>();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Scan scan = new Scan();
                scan.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BID)));
                scan.setIsbn(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BISBN)));
                scan.setQuantity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_QUANTITY)));
                scan.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BPRICE)));
                scan.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE)));
                scan.setAuthor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_AUTHOR)));
                scan.setIePrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_IE)));
                scan.setMaxLimit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_LIMIT)));
                scan.setSupply(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_SUPPLY)));
                scans.add(scan);
            }
        }
        return scans;
    }

    public boolean addToMyScans(Scan scan) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BISBN, scan.getIsbn());
        values.put(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_QUANTITY, "1");
        values.put(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BPRICE, scan.getPrice());
        long result = database.insert(ScanDBOpenHelper.TABLE_BUYS, null, values);
        scan.setId(result);
        return (result != -1);
    }

    public boolean removeFromMyScans(Scan scan) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "removeFromMyScans started");
        String where = ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BID + "=" + scan.getId();
        int result = database.delete(ScanDBOpenHelper.TABLE_BUYS, where, null);
        return (result == 1);
    }

    public boolean updateMyScans(Scan scan) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "update started");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BPRICE, scan.getPrice());
        values.put(ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_QUANTITY, scan.getQuantity());
        String where = ScanDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_BID + "=" + scan.getId();
        int result = database.update(ScanDBOpenHelper.TABLE_BUYS, values, where, null);
        return (result == 1);
    }

    public List<Scan> findMyScans() {
        String query = "SELECT buys_id,quantity, buyer_temp.price, scan_final.* "
                + " FROM buyer_temp inner join scan_final on scan_final.isbn = buyer_temp.isbn";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");

        List<Scan> scans = cursorToScanned(cursor);
        return scans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a crash? Have you looked for a stack trace in Logcat?

Comment: I do get the stopped working notification and that I have a fatal error on line...  which is the line where my if statement is.

Comment: Logcat says it is a NullPointerException at that line.

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Add here your `XML` file of `Activity` where you are calling `doDelete()` method.

Comment: Can you share `ScanDataSource` class code?

Comment: @ManishMulimani ScanDataSource is added.  Everything except for the update and remove functions works perfectly.

Comment: What's the last `Log.i` output that you see? `delete clicked` or `going to delete`?

Comment: going to delete is the last one

Comment: Is the message `Database opened scans` printed in logcat?

Comment: yes, and then the next item is the "going to delete" log. Even if i remove the datasource.open(); is still get the errors.

Comment: You should initialize your `datasource` before `datasource.open()`. At this point it is null.

Comment: @Jim modify `doDelete` like this: http://pastebin.com/gyFGHGCU and then post log messages you receive (along with stacktrace)

Comment: @Idolon Still got the Null pointer exception.  I updated the stack trace above

Comment: @Jim First - I can't see `going to delete` logs there; second - there is `Database closed` line right before delete clicked. Who calls that? Can you post related code? Also can you please tell what is written at line #62 in your `ScanDataSource.java` file. Is it `datasource.open()` there?. (You can go to line number with `Ctrl+L` combination in Eclipse or `Ctrl+G` in IDEA)

Comment: @Jim there is a typo in my last comment, I meant line #62 of **`ScanDetailActivity`** file

Comment: @Idolon the close is called by an onPause function. 
  protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   datasource.close();
  } Line 62 is the datasource.open() line.

Comment: @Idolon based on your advice I moved the <code>datasource = new ScanDataSource(this);
  datasource.open();</code> into the on create and it works perfectly now.  if you write it up as an aswer, the county is yours!!  Thanks for all the time you put into this on my behalf.

Comment: @Jim Glad to hear you solved it, I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs and your comments the reason of the exception is that `datasource` is `null` in your `doDelete` method. Search the code for places where you init `datasource` field and where you set it to `null`. It could happen that you initialize it in the `onCreate` method but set to `null` in the `onPause` or `onStop`. (This will not work since `onCreate` is not called again after activity has been stopped, but not destroyed. Check [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) for the details).